# Array to String to append to a textArea in a JFrame GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist<ActivityPerformed> activityPerformed` that I want to print into a `textArea` as a part of a `String printReport()`.

This is what I have right now (located in Tracker.class)

```
public String getActivityPerformed() {
    String done = "";
    String error = "No tracked activities.\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < activityPerformed.size(); i++) {
        done += activityPerformed.get(i);
        done += "\n";
        return done;
    }
    return error;
}

public String printReport()
{   
    lifestyleReport  = "\n \nLifestyle Report \n";
    lifestyleReport += "Activities Performed \n" + getActivityPerformed();
    return lifestyleReport;
}
```

}

And this is what I have for the GUI (TrackerGUI.class):

```
public class Report implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
        if(tracker.foodEaten.isEmpty() == true && tracker.activityPerformed.isEmpty() == true)
            textArea.append("Error: No food/activity tracked. \n");
        else textArea.append(tracker.printReport());
    }
}
```

What do I add to the code to make the array print into the `textArea` properly? I always get something like this: @365bc793

Comment: Did you override the `toString` method in your class?

Comment: No. How do I do that? I've been seeing it when I searched for answers, but I really didn't understand how it worked since most of the solutions were based on `System.out.print`

Comment: Here's an example: http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < activityPerformed.size(); i++) {
            done += activityPerformed.get(i);
                                        ^------------Object of ActivityPerformed
            done += "\n";
            return done;
        }
```

In the above code, you are getting the element index i from the list but the type is of `ActivityPerformed` due to which when you print on textarea the object get printed.

Comment: Can you please expound on that? I didn't really understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: List is of type ActivityPerformed, mean list will contain object of this class.When u try to get any element with index then it will return the object of the ActivityPerformed.So i m not sure which attribute of class ActivityPerformed u want to saw in the report.

Answer (score 1):

Each time an object is transformed to a String by concatenation, as in

```
done += activityPerformed.get(i);
```

its `toString()` method is called. Every object has such a method, because all Java classes inherit from `java.lang.Object`, which has a default implementation of this method. This default implementation, however, only returns the type of the object and its hashCode. So, if you want to return something different, you have to override toString() in your class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hello, I'm an ActivityPerformed, and my name is " + this.name;
}
```

So, either do that, or print specific values from your object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < activityPerformed.size(); i++) {
    ActivityPerformed a = activityPerformed.get(i)
    done += a.getName();
    done += " - "
    done += a.getFoo();
    done += "\n";
}
```

Also, note that you should favor the foreach loop:

```
for (ActivityPerformed a : activityPerformed) {
    done += ...
}
```

Also note that you shouldn't return from inside the loop, otherwise you'll only have the first element of the list in your string.

And finally, you should use a StringBuilder to make your code efficient. Not doing that will create a whole lot of temporary objects and be inefficient:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (ActivityPerformed a : activityPerformed) {
    builder.append(...);
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: To clarify: would the `builder.append(...)` contain the `done += ..` parts that you specified above? Also, do I need to import or declare anything for `getFoo()` to work? I'm getting a 'cannot find symbol - method getFoo' error.

Comment: builder.append() appends something to the builder. Once you have appended everything, you get the full string from the builder, using builder.toString(). Read the javadoc. You'll learn by reading documentation. I don't know anything about your ActivityPerformed class, so I imagined it had a getFoo() method returning what you want to print in the text area. This is not code to cut 'n paste without understanding. This is example code illustrating the principles you should follow. Replace getFoo() and getName() by what you want to get and print from the ActivityPerformed objects.

Comment: D'oh, I belatedly realised what the `getName()` and `getFoo()` equivalents were for my code (I had a different name for it). We've never discussed `StringBuilder` in class, though (Beginner's Java), so I can't use it for my code. It worked with the `a.getName()` and `a.getFoo()` (though in my case it was `getTotalCalories()`). Thank you!

Comment: There are thousands of classes in the JDK alone, and you'll use many additional libraries. If you only use classes you've discussed in class, you won't get far. A huge part of a developer's job is to read documentation and learn to use new classes in an autonomous way.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. The problem is, this is _for_ my Beginner's Java class, and my professor deducts points if we use code we haven't discussed in class yet. I'll start tinkering and experimenting with more codes once we learn more about the basics.

Comment: The more I hear how teachers teach these days, the more I'm depressed. Sigh.